# The trickier part of a backup: The restoration

Tags: backup, rsync, restore

I would like to make the backup process of my system as sensible and efficient as possible. (Well, not as possible maybe, but a little bit at least.) In this course, the  backup itself is the most straight-forward part. I am trying to backup *only* the stuff that is personal to me, i. e. configuration data for the system and applications, and personal data. Therefore, I am utilising the following `rsync` command:

```
sudo rsync -avRXA  --progress --delete /home /etc /var/lib /var/backups /usr/local /opt /srv /media/externalhdd
```

In order to decide which directories to backup I mainly followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/what-directories-do-i-need-to-back-up. So I explicitly want to exclude the applications and "the operating system itself" from the backup.

However, this in turn makes the restoration just as trickier. I need to install Ubuntu from scratch and then restore the user data separately, but I think I have to be cautious not to produce inconsistencies by carrying out those two steps successively.

For example: `apt` or `dpkg` resp. store their information about installed packages in `/var/lib/apt` and `/var/lib/dpkg`. This is in my above backup approach regarded as user-related data and will be restored out of the backup, but the packages themselves have to be installed manually on the new system prior to this.

I am worried that in the end I am mixing up parts installed from scratch and parts that are restored from backup which do not go well with each other. Are my concerns reasonable and what can I do to overcome these? What do I have to keep in mind if I set up an installation from scratch and then override parts of the systems with data from my backup?

An alternative would of course always be to backup the entire system and restore it as one. But that is not the challenge I would like to take up for now.

Comment: You are on the right track. Your personal data should be in your /home directory, s back up all of that...except the `dbus` and `.cache` directories. One is owned by root, the other is transient data. Any extra jobs or services that you create (like a cron job and backup script) should also be backed up. I keep a text file (in the format of a heavily-commented shell script) on a different server that details exactly how to do recovery. Whenever I add something new, I see of it needs to be backed up. If so, I edit both the backup job *and* the recovery script right away before I forget..

Comment: I do a very similar backup, however I have found that reinstalling all of the applications is far easier than attempting to find and recopy all of the components, and I use a largish script for that purpose.  Thus, all of the data that I need to include is in my /home directory, and everything else is just OS parts.  Often in addition to the directories mentioned by @user535733 I also remove the .config directory, as the configurations seem to cause occasional problems with new installations.

Comment: BTW - Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I have seen similar questions to yours closed as being 'opinion based', so if this happens, please do not be discouraged.

Comment: "m as sensible and efficient as possible."   clonezilla.org , a one pass complete backup of partitions and drives. free.

Comment: Thank you! But still my fear is that any GUI program could have stored something outside of my home directory, which I don't know about, and I miss it. Is that not likely to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an excellent idea to use rsync to backup your personal data. These are data that are unique and cannot be replaced. Once lost, these are lost forever.

I would not bother trying to backup system files along. Once an operating system is lost, a better version of it is easily downloaded and installed in less than an hour.

If you insist on having a backup of system configuration, by which you can easily restore older configurations, then I recommend you install and use Timeshift. Timeshift is a utility specifically designed to create system snapshots. Under the hood, it can work in rsync mode, where it used rsync, or can work in btrfs mode if you use that file system. It is very good quality software *designed for system snapshots* (*not* for personal data), and a testimony of that can be that it is installed in the Linux Mint distribution by default.

So in the end, use **rsync** as normal user to backup your user data on external media like a USB drive. A good backup of your user data is mandatory and indispensable. Optionally, use a tool like Timeshift to backup system configuration. In rsync mode, these backups can also be on an external volume.